# jQuery - How can I get the value of any word when my mouse is hovering over it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover, cpu-word

In jQuery, when my mouse hovers over a word inside an element, I would like to get its value.

For example, if I have a paragraph with this text

```
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
```

When I hover over a particular word, such as `this`, I'd like to get its text.

Comment: You would have to wrap each word in span tags dynamically. Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 2):

For every div, we search for each word and wrap it in `span` tags.

We will listen for the `mouseover` event and add a highlight class, to highlight the word we are targeting. We can then get that span's html. We remove the class on the `mouseout` event.

```js
$('div').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/\b(\w+)\b/g, "<span>$1</span>"));
});

$('div span').on("mouseover", function() {
    $(this).addClass('highlight'); 
        $("#result").html(getWord($(this).html()));
    }).on("mouseout", function() {
        $(this).removeClass('highlight'); 
    });

function getWord(word){
    return word;
}
```

```css
span {
  font-size: 15pt;
}

.highlight {
  background: #ffff66;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <span>This text is a  test text</span>
</div>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: thx, but i need to get just the word, not text include in <p></p>

Comment: do you think it is possible to do that without embed my word in tag? ( here span )

Comment: Yes, we are not manually entering span tags. We are creating span tags dynamically. Without that, I don't think it's possible though

Comment: great idea richard thx .. do you know i can spanned a text with is composed by - ? for example seventy-five ? ( result should be <span>seventy-five</span> and not <span>seventy</span><span>-</span><span>five</span> thx

Comment: hi richard. i have problem with your regex because html tags ( <br /> for example ) are deleted .. do you know why ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("*").not("body").mouseover(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
  }); 
});
```

this piece of code is applicable for all tags except body tag..

Answer (score 0):

```
//everything on the page, avoiding the body, who has the entiry text of the page
$(document).on('mouseenter',':not(body)',function(){
//1 - get the text 
    var text = $(this).text();

    //2 - verify if text is not empty
    if(text != ''){

        //3 - break the text by lines, you choose
           text = text.split('\n');

        //4- get only the first line, you choose
           text = text[0];

        //5 verify again if is not empty
           if(text != ''){
               //write on console
               console.log(text);
            }
     }
});
```